# Ansible | Process data which can be either JSON or YAML

Tags: json, ansible, yaml

I'm using Ansible to read a config, which can be either JSON or YAML and extract values from some of the nodes in the file.

I know I can use `from_json` or `from_yaml` to process it in Ansible, but since I don't know which format the config will be in, I'm having difficulty making it work.

The file is Kubernetes' Kubeconfig. Examples below:

in YAML

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://my-k8s-cluster.com
  name: k8s-clstr-master
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: k8s-clstr-master
    namespace: kube-system
    user: k8s-clstr-master-admin
  name: k8s-clstr-master
current-context: k8s-clstr-master
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: k8s-clstr-master-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

in JSON

```
{
    "kind": "Config",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "preferences": {},
    "clusters": [
        {
            "name": "k8s-clstr-master",
            "cluster": {
                "server": "https://my-k8s-cluster.com",
                "certificate-authority-data": "REDACTED"
            }
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "k8s-clstr-master-admin",
            "user": {
                "client-certificate-data": "REDACTED",
                "client-key-data": "REDACTED"
            }
        }
    ],
    "contexts": [
        {
            "name": "k8s-clstr-master",
            "context": {
                "cluster": "k8s-clstr-master",
                "user": "k8s-clstr-master-admin",
                "namespace": "kube-system"
            }
        }
    ],
    "current-context": "k8s-clstr-master"
}
```

Ansible I'm using:

```
vars:
  kubeconfig: "{{ lookup('hashivault', '/kubeconfig/admin', 'config') }}"

tasks:
  - name: Find cluster server name
    shell: "echo {{ kubeconfig.clusters[0].cluster.server }}"
```

Above Ansible block will work okay if `kubeconfig` is retrieved in JSON format, but it will fail if it's retrieved as in YAML format.

I might be able to make a task with `|from yaml` and then add `ignore_errors: true`, but that just doesn't feel like right way of doing it.

Anyone has any tips for me on how I can approach this problem?

Comment: Are you aware that YAML is a superset of JSON and therefore you can simply load any JSON document as YAML?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't know how to.

Comment: Just always use `from_yaml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [built-in tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-tests) in Jinja2.

The way Ansible templator works if you have JSON string inside `{{...}}` expression, it is automatically converted to object. So if you fetch JSON from your vault, `kubeconfig` becomes object, otherwise it is a string.

Here's a recipe for you:

```
vars:
  kubeconfig_raw: "{{ lookup('hashivault', '/kubeconfig/admin', 'config') }}"
  kubeconfig: "{{ kubeconfig_raw if kubeconfig_raw is mapping else kubeconfig_raw | from_yaml }}"

tasks:
  - name: Find cluster server name
    shell: "echo {{ kubeconfig.clusters[0].cluster.server }}"
```

Comment: Thanks `if kubeconfig_raw is mapping` was just the thing I was looking for. And thanks for thanks for the built-in tests link!

Answer (score 1):

If you use the [`include_vars`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/include_vars_module.html) task, it does not matter which format you provide. The task accepts both.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: config
        name: kubeconfig
    - debug: var=kubeconfig
```